# Which tasks can be visually confirmed by other crew members?

Tags: among-us

Some tasks, such as 'Submit Scan' in the Medbay, have a visual animation/indicator that other players can see, thereby allowing them to 'vouch' for whoever did the scan. Other tasks don't have any indicator, leaving you to guess if the player standing by a console or wall is legitimate or just pretending.

I know that sometimes you can determine if a task was completed based on the 'Completed Tasks' tracker/bar increasing, but this isn't reliable with larger player numbers, and the impostors can see it too, so it can be gamed.

Which tasks can be visually verified while underway, or at completion? And for a given task, what visual indicator should one be looking for?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The following tasks have visual indicators:

### MedBay: Submit Scan (The Skeld, Mira HQ, Polus)

While scanning, a green hologram will surround the crewmate, moving up and then down.
[image: A hologram scanning the player.]

### Shields: Prime Shields (The Skeld)

Upon completion, the shields to the lower-right of the room will activate and turn yellow. If this task was already completed, completing it again will cause the lights to pulse.

**These shields are off:**
[image: The location of the shields.]

**And these are on:**
[image: Activated shields]

### Storage Room: Empty Garbage (The Skeld)

This is a two-part task. The second part always takes place in the Storage Room, and upon completion, you can see garbage ejecting from the bottom of the ship.

[image: Garbage being ejected.]

### Weapons: Clear Asteroids (The Skeld, Polus)

When the crewmate fires the weapons (by clicking / tapping on the screen), the weapons outside of the Weapons room will fire a laser. On The Skeld, these are on the right of the room ; on Polus, these are outside the room, on the left, and are visible from outside.

**This is where the weapons are on The Skeld:**
[image: Location of the weapons on The Skeld.]

**This is what it looks like for weapons on The Skeld to fire:** *
[image: Weapons firing on The Skeld]

**This is what it looks like for weapons on Polus to fire:**
[image: Weapons firing on Polus]

---

<sup>* Image credit: [Among Us Wiki](https://among-us.fandom.com/wiki/Visual_Tasks?file=Skeld_clear_asteroids.png)</sup>

Comment: Another point is that the MedBay: Submit Scan task can be verified even with visual tasks off. Only one crewmate can do it at a time, and if another tries to do it it will say "Waiting for [player name]".

Comment: And the MedBay scan also "snaps" the crewmate to the middle of the platform when it begins, so that can be a non-confirming hint.

Comment: @TheLibrarian It's important to note that even ghost players can block like this.

Comment: @Kroltan I think this only occurs on your own screen, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @CaptainMan yes but it will say waiting for [name] so you will know if its a ghost because lets say im waiting on Jeff to scan, and jeff is not standing with me I know jeff is a ghost

Comment: @Penguin I'm not saying you won't know it's a ghost, I'm just saying it can happen.

Comment: Long tasks like Start Reactor can also be used as bait. Since imposters actually fake tasks, they also have to fake it for the time it takes to actually complete that task, and that would be an imposter's gamble. Just dropping a big hint.

Answer (score 9):

1. Medbay scan can be verified during the scan by seeing a green field around them while they are doing it.
2. Asteroids/weapons will show the cannons firing during the task
3. Some trash tasks such as bottom trash on Skeld will show trash falling out upon completion.
4. Shields on Skeld will show lights that turn on outside the ship for the first person who does it.
5. All tasks that are not multipart tasks will have the task bar move when completed, and the final task in a multipart task will also cause the bar to move. Multipart tasks are things like Wires, Upload/Download, Trash, Repair node.

This all depends on the game setting though, as you can turn off visual tasks and the task bar verification.